# SQS FIFO not sending emails in the correct order

Tags: amazon-sqs

Currently I have SQS setup to process emails which are sent from a node service.

The data is driven from a database and ordered correctly so that these can be processed as FIFO.

We then run a job to send the emails using SES. However the emails are being still sent randomly.

To test this I have to console log before sending the email:

```
return aws.ses
      .sendEmail(params)
      .promise()
      .then(() => {
        return aws.sqs.deleteMessage(PARAMS HERE).promise();
      });
```

Running out of ideas?

Any help would be great

Thanks

T

Comment: What is reading message from the queue? Is it a single-threaded application that grabs one SQS message at a time, sending the SES message? Or do you have multiple workers pulling SQS messages? The question is whether your problem lies in the order of retrieval from SQS, or in the sending of SES messages, or in the order of _receipt_ of SES messages.

Comment: It is single threaded so we have SQS queue. Do when monitoring the the sqs queue the first item email sent is sat at the bottom. But when reading from the sqs and sending the email using ses the order is incorrect

Comment: How are you judging this? Is it based on the order of receipt in your email system? You really need to look at the logs generated by your app to confirm that it is pulling messages in the correct order and sending them in the correct order. What happens after SES sends emails is out of AWS control.